# How would I alter the hue and sharpness of an image on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I would like to be able to adjust the hue and sharpness of an image for display within a UIImageView in my iPhone application.

How would I process an image to alter these characteristics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried ImageMajick - I believe there has been some success porting it to iOS:

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=14089

Answer (score 1):

Apple's [GLImageProcessing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html) sample application has routines for adjusting the hue and sharpness of an image using OpenGL ES 1.1.